# Prove the Mobius function relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products, mobius-function

I have a proof of the following relation:

$$\prod_{d|n} \frac{17-(6\mu(d)+1)^2}{16}=1$$

where the $\mu(d)$ is Mobius function.

The way I have proved it is very long and even putting it here is not realistic. And I think the way I went is not the right way in terms of efficiency.
Could you please help with finding a simple way to prove this relation?

EDIT: I need to add that it is true for $n>1$.
Here is maple code for testing.

> with(NumberTheory):
>
> seq(simplify(1-mul(1/16*(17-(6*Moebius(d)+1)^2), d = numtheory:-divisors(n))), n = 1 .. 100)

Comment: Can you at least say something about what approach you used?

Comment: I used the following identity proving of which is enough long $\prod_{d|n} \frac{2(k+1)+k\mu(d)(k\mu(d)+k+2)}{2(k+1)}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(n) = \frac{17-(6\mu(n)+1)^2}{16} = (-2)^{\mu(n)}$$

Thus $$\prod_{d | n} f(d) =(- 2)^{\sum_{d | n} \mu(d)} = 1 \text{ for } n > 1, = -2 \text{ for } n = 1$$

Comment: Nice, Could you please explain the first relation?

Comment: $\mu(n)$ takes $3$ possible values..

Comment: I see if we check 3 possible values for $\mu(n)$, we just get to proper result.

Comment: Yes. I think I follow your idea! It might be interesting to investigate the  polynomial on  $\mu(n)$. I mean in terms of product over divisors.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan I meant $P(\mu(d))$. If I give you **any** polynomial $Q(x)$, can you evaluate $\prod_{d | n} Q(\mu(d))$ ?

Comment: It should be possible, I assume. Because of 3 possible values of $\mu(d)$. Will think about this.